# Change window title in Alacritty

Tags: gnome, kde, xfce, lxde, lxqt

I would like to change what appears on Alacritty window title.
I would like it to display only "Alacritty" or "Terminal" instead of the current path.
I have changed the title tag on alacritty.yml but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was solved by adding "dynamic_title: false" to alacritty.yml